# regular expression split also includes empty string result

Tags: python

Where is the empty string coming from ?
I want the result to be `['a','3']`

```
 import re
 a = 'a,/3'
 print re.split(r'[/,]',a) 
 # gives ['a', '', '3']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty string is the expected result. The regex

```
"[/,]"
```

means "split on either a '/' or ','"

As you have both in a row, the split returns the empty string between them.

You can achieve your desired behavior by using `findall` instead of `sub`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^/,]', a)
['a', '3']
```

Comment: Thanks,  if it means "split on either a '/' or ','" that is what I want.  Still not clear about the part about them being in a row

Comment: @airnet No problem. I agree it's not necessary clear to me why that's the default - I usually find the behavior undesirable myself. `str.split()` has the same effect, e.g. `"...".split('.') = ['', '', '', '']`.

Comment: oh ok, I see the pattern